# Conditional URL scraping with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy on a site which I do not know the URL structure of.

I would like to:

- **only** extract data from pages which contain Xpath "//div[@class="product-view"]".
- extract print (in CSV) the URL, the name and price Xpaths

When I run the below script, all I get is a random list of URL's

`scrapy crawl dmoz>test.txt`

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

DOMAIN = 'site.com'
URL = 'http://%s' % DOMAIN

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url
            if response.xpath('//div[@class="product-view"]'):
                url = response.extract()
                name = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]/h1/text()').extract()
                price = response.xpath('//span[@class="product_price_details"]/text()').extract()
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
            print url
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are lookin here is for [scrapy.spiders.Crawlspider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#crawlspider).

However you almost got it with your own approach. Here's the fixed version.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
def parse(self, response):
    # parse this page
    if response.xpath('//div[@class="product-view"]'):
        item = dict()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="product_price_details"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item  # return an item with your data
    # other pages
    le = LinkExtractor()  # linkextractor is smarter than xpath '//a/@href'
    for link in le.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(link.url)  # default callback is already self.parse
```

Now you can simply run `scrapy crawl myspider -o results.csv` and scrapy will output csv of your items. Though keep an eye on the log and the stats bit at the end especially, that's how you know if something went wrong